# In “she's already ensconced in her new job", what does "s" stand for? is or has?

Tags: tense

> She's already ensconced in her new job.

"Has already" is a familiar structure to me, while in this sentence, knowing that "ensconce" is a transitive verb, which means that "she" is definitely its object, "is already" turns out to be the appropriate answer. It is the first time I have come across a problem like this and I wonder what exactly "is already" is trying to convey. Does it express the same meaning as "have/has been doing something"?

Comment: I'm unclear what the ambiguity is. Do you think it might be, "*She **has** already ensconced in her new job*"? That's ungrammatical because, as you've already mentioned, "ensconce" is a transitive verb. Feel free to edit your question to include what you see as the other possibility(-ies).

Comment: "is already" here mostly just means that she took a short time to adjust to her new job.

Answer (score 1):

> She's already ensconced in her new job.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ensconced) defines ensconced and gives a similar example.

> adjective [ after verb ]   literary
>
> positioned safely or comfortably somewhere:
> He is now firmly ensconced in his new home.

Your example uses this adjective form and means she is already positioned comfortably in her new job.

> She is already ensconced in her new job.

**ensconce**, as a verb, is defined in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ensconce) as follows.

> ensconce yourself
>
> to make yourself very comfortable or safe in a place or position:
> After dinner, I ensconced myself in an armchair with a book.

To use this definition,  we could say

> She **has** already ensconced **herself** in her new job.

Answer (score -1):

A think it depends on context where it's used. If someone pushed he, an answer is "she is encountered". If she moved herself, she "has encountered"